# Bin packing with item weight constraint

Tags: np, bin-packing

In the bin packing problem, we are given a set of items I={a1,...,an}, each item with weight w_a1,...,w_an, and a set of n bins with B={b1,..., bn} all bins with capacity C. I want to restrict the weights of the items to be polynomial in n. Is the problem still being NP-hard (restricting the weight of the items)?

Any information and sources about this would be appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: While this question isn't off-topic for SO, its theoretical nature means you may get better answers at cs.stackexchange.com. (You also get free MathJax, which is nice.)

Comment: Thanks, I will move the question there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I placed the question at cs.stackexchange.com, as suggested by Jeroen Mostert, and found the answer. Here is the link, https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/87894/bin-packing-with-item-weight-constraint, in case that someone needs it.